# Can't maintain session in VB.net subfolder

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm working with an old VB based ASP form website. I'm in the process of converting parts of it to C#. For that I created a subfolder in App_Code and registered it in web.config. 
I have a set of VB webservices consumed by desktop apps, I translated them to C# in my subfolder but they can't seem to keep a session persistent (they keep creating new ones).

1. As a test I created a new VB class in App_Code with a simple "ping" method and I trace the session id to see if a new one is created. When called from desktop app the session persists correctly.
2. Same test from the subfolder (in C#), the session is always new (does not persist)
3. Calling subfolder class ping method from the VB test class result in losing session persistence as well.

So called from a desktop app, the VB test inApp_Code keep session, the C# test in subfolder doesn't keep session, the C# test in subfolder being passed a session by VB test in App_Code doesn't keep session.
Called from website itself, session is kept and persist in all cases.

Cannot find much information at all online about cases even remotely similar.

How to keep a session persistent when webservice in App_code subfolder is called by a desktop app?

The VB class declaration in App_Code:

```
<WebService(Namespace:="xxxxxx")>
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
Public Class VBTest
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
```

The VBTest ping method:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> <ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> Public Function Ping(ByVal request As String) As String
Session.SessionID ' this id is the same between calls coming from a desktop app
```

The C# class declaration in App_Code subfolder:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "xxxxx")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class CTest : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

And its 'ping' method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void Ping(String request = null)
Session.SessionID // this id is different after each call from a desktop app
// how to keep this id the same? (make it persist)
```

Comment: Using New will always create a new instance of the object and a new connection.  To continue using the same connection you must use the same instance of the object.  You are using Web Config so the Request should always be the same instance but the response should be new after each message is sent.

Comment: I don't understand that, I'm only referencing the Session, not explicitly creating a new one.

Comment: What code are you using inc# that deals with sessions?  Normally c# has Clients,Server, listener.

Comment: What do you mean desktop app, it's a web page? I'm not to sure how you do your test. If you compile each time, the session will be cleared.

Comment: See the edits, the webservices are part of a ASP form website, if called from that website (in a simple page) the session persist correctly, if called from external (liek a desktop app) the session does not persist if I call the C# service in App_Code subfolder but still works fine for the VB service in App_Code

Comment: as @jsweng has said, how are you calling the webservice in your desktop app? you should persist with the one `HttpClient` instance for example and not declare `new HttpClient` for each call.

Comment: See my edits, I really don't do anything special, my desktop app call any of those 2 services the same way, the VB one has session persistence, the C# one doesn't. Could it be because it's C# in a subfolder in a VB website? Could it be because it's a subfolder?

Comment: Update, if I put the exact same C# code in a .dll and put in in my bin and use that then I get a persistent session from a desktop app call. This is good enough to fix my problem but still what's wrong with subfolders? What's so special about them that they can't keep sessions?